Генератор обратного отсчета на голом php
Вопрос такого характера возможно ли сделать генератор обратного отсчета секунд на голом php.
Заранее спасибо

Чисто технически можно) используя например https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php в цикле while (true).. в котором каждую секунду будет куда-то что-то отправляться/выполняться.. если же это страничка сайта - то тут без JS вообще все плохо будет) опишите задачу и тд, больше конкретики

Примерно как-то так:
<?php
$counter = 10;

while ( $counter > 0 ) {
    echo $counter;    
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
    
    $counter--;
}


ob_end_flush();

можно включить принудительный выброс из буфера:
<?php
ob_end_flush();
ob_implicit_flush(true);

$counter = 10;

while ( $counter > 0 ) {
    echo $counter;    
    sleep(1);    
    $counter--;
}

